# NoClassDefFoundError when compiling javac from cmd?

Tags: java, cmd

My folder `c:\users\owner\desktop\test` contains two files : `opencsv-2.3.jar` and `Test.jar`

Here is the code for Test.jar

```
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import au.com.bytecode.opencsv.CSVReader;

public class Test {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(
        new FileReader("C:\\Users\\owner\\Desktop\\test.csv"));
    String[] newLine;
    while ((newLine = reader.readNext()) != null) {
      System.out.println(newLine[0]);
    }
  }
}
```

I tried running this from cmd as following

```
cd c:\users\owner\desktop\test\
javac -cp "c:\users\owner\desktop\test\opencsv-2.3.jar;" Test.java
```

It compiles okay and and `Test.class` is created . But when I try to run it , it throws an error `NoClassDefFoundError`

```
java Test
```

I looked up similar questions online, but it seems that most of them had an issue because they did not specify the `package` name when running it from cmd. I do NOT have any package `(default)` . Why am I getting this error ?

Comment: give your package version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to give your `classpath` in input along with the Java the command:

```
java -classpath .;c:\users\owner\desktop\test\opencsv-2.3.jar; Test
```

or, more compact version:

```
java -cp .;c:\users\owner\desktop\test\opencsv-2.3.jar; Test
```

And **don't forget** the '`.`' (common newbie mistake, generally source of headaches), as it states you're including the current working directory to the `classpath`!

Further documentation available [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/classpath.html#BEHJBHCD)  (Windows) and [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/unix/classpath.html#BEHJBHCD) (Unix).

Comment: Thank you. It works perfect. But I did not include `.` and it still works `java -cp "c:\users\owner\desktop\test\opencsv-2.3.jar;" Test` Why do I need the `.` ,  if it works without it ?

Comment: Probably because your application is not included in a package/namespace. Anyway, believe me, just include it *every time* to avoid headaches...

Answer (score 1):

Execute it like this

```
java -cp .;pathOfyourjar className // for windows

java -cp .:pathOfyourjar className // for linux-like environment
```